# I Can't create 2 objects off superclass in subclass using super();

Tags: java, oop

I have a Superclass 'Telefoon' (english: Telephone). this superclass has a child/subclass 'ContactGegevens' (Egnlish Contact data/user Information). This subclass 'ContactGegevnes' is a superclass of a child/subclass as well but is not relevant for my question.

In Super class 'Telefoon' (Telephone).

```
public class Telefoon {

//Properties.
private String soort; //Enlgish = Type (Mobile or landline)
private String nummer; //English = Number (Just the number).

//Getters and Setters.
//Just normal getters and setters of all properties. not relevant to show here.    

//Constructors.
public Telefoon(String soort, String nummer) {
    this.nummer = nummer;
    this.soort = soort;
}

/** This constructor does nothing but when I don't have this one it gives and error in the child 
class??? */
public Telefoon() {
    this.nummer = "000000000";
    this.soort = "vast";
}

//Methods.
//Not relevant for question.
```

Child/Subclass 'ContactGegevens'.

```
public class ContactGegevens extends Telefoon {

//Properties.
private String eMail;         //Email.
private Telefoon telefoon;    //Landline number.
private Telefoon gsm;         //Mobile phone number.

//Getters and Setters.
//Getters and Setters of all 3 properties. irrelevant to show here

//Constructors.
public ContactGegevens(String vast, String mobiel, String eMail) {
    /**
    *This works but in this case the 'extends Telefoon' is useless???!!
    As you can see I create 2 objects of superClass Telefoon. But then the 'extends Telefoon'
    is unnecessary, is there a Way i can do something like 

    telefoon = Super();
    gsm = Super(); 

    */
    telefoon = new Telefoon(vast,"vast");
    gsm = new Telefoon(mobiel, "mobiel");
    this.eMail = eMail;
}

//Methods.
public String toString() {
    return String.format("E-mail: %-15s %nTel: %-12s %nGSM: %-12s",eMail,telefoon.getNummer(), gsm.getNummer());
}
```

My problem is that The class 'ContactGegevens' extends Telefoon
But in the constructor of ContactGegevens I still have to create 2 objects of class Telefoon rendering
'Extends Telefoon' useless. Can I do something like Telefoon telefoon = Super(//Param here);?

And also Why do I need a default constructor in Telefoon otherwise I get an error when instantiating the
object 'Telefoon' in the constructor of 'ContactGegevens'.

Comment: your logic is flawed. That shouldn't be a subclass. Also, you don't have to have a default constructor, but if you remove it, you'll need your constructor(s) in your subclass have an explicit call to an existing constructor

Comment: I thought that too, and I know school homework is considered by some to be not allowed here but Yes this is an exercise (first year in college just started OOP programming) and in the exercise it is explicitly stated that the superclass HAS to be a superclass of the childclass since we are now learning about it

Comment: “school homework is considered by some to be not allowed here” — No, questions about homework are *definitely* allowed here. What’s not allowed is *cheating* on homework (and, just to be clear, nothing here indicates cheating).

Comment: Yes I know but I don't think of it as cheating because these exercises are not seen in school they are optional, they are not graded and just are there for you to exercise more on the subject we learned.  I also did not just paste the exercise. I made the exercise and don't understand something about it and thus I asked a question here to help me understand What I don't fully get

Comment: @NielsVanSteen yes, but it is completely bonkers. Look at it this way: in logic, would ContactGegevens pass an IS A test on Telephone? No. So, there is no way this should be a subclass. ContactGegevens will pass a HAS A Telephone(Number) test, though. This is not inheritance, it's composition

Comment: Yes than I got my answer, just as I did not see any reason for inheritance and thought I didn't understand somehting, there is actually no reason for inheritance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, the `ContactGegevens` class shouldn’t inherit from `Telefoon`, because it does not satisfy the “is-a” logic of inheritance. Instead, it *has* multiple phone numbers.

But given the constraint you’re operating with, I would suggest removing the `telefoon` member from `ContactGegevens`: it’s replaced by the inheritance. This leaves us with:

```
public class ContactGegevens extends Telefoon {
    private String eMail;         //Email.
    private Telefoon gsm;         //Mobile phone number.

    public ContactGegevens(String vast, String mobiel, String eMail) {
        super("vast", vast);
        this.eMail = eMail;
        gsm = new Telefoon("mobiel", mobiel);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("E-mail: %-15s %nTel: %-12s %nGSM: %-12s", eMail, getNummer(), gsm.getNummer());
    }
```

Comment: according to the logic you coded, every fixed phone has a cellphone.
... still makes little sense. There 's also no reason to pass "vast" or "mobiel" as parameters, since you still have seperate instances for them

Comment: @Stultuske Well, Konrad Rudolph explicitly said that the style is already FUBAR. Basically, OP asks for a ridiculous constraint (ContactGegevens must extend Telefoon which is idiotic), and is trying to do the best possible within this crazy constraint.